# 2 Ethernet ports 1 vpn

Tags: vpn, internet, ethernet

On my desktop I would like to have 1 ethernet port for interent going in and out but not a vpn and the 2nd ethernet port connected with a vpn going to a tv. Hope that makes sense. I would be using Nord vpn if that matters. I have read " Sharing VPN connection from Windows PC using a wire" on Nords website. I would like to only have the tv connected to a vpn not the desktop.Is this possible thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the two different ethernet ports with IP addresses on different subnets with different default gateways, that way you can define which traffic is allocated to the TV and which is internet

From what you are saying I don't see why you need the VPN for the TV. Can't you connect the TV directly to your router for internet connectivity?.

What exactly are you trying to achieve with this configuration if you are not wanting the TV to interact with the Desktop?